# if $G$ has average degree $d$, then there exists a subgraph with minimum degree at least $d/2$

Tags: graph-theory

Say we have a graph $G$ of average degree at least $d$. I want to show that we can find an induced subgraph with minimum degree at least $d/2$. The idea is to repeatedly delete vertices of degree smaller than $d/2$ from $G$, as long as there are such vertices. This should increase the average degree, but I’m not sure how to show that. First we have
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nd_i}{n}=d,
$$
where $d_i$ is the degree of the $i$th vertex. Say there exists a vertex of degree $k<d/2$. If we delete this vertex, our average degree becomes
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nd_i-2k}{n-1}.
$$
I need to show that this number is greater, using the fact that $2k<d$, but I'm not sure how. Any ideas?

Comment: I was stuck at this problem and was looking for some hints when I came upon this thread. I like the idea of deleting vertices, but develop it a bit differently. The deletion would consist of several steps, in each one we delete vertices of degree less than $\frac{d}{2}$. We claim that this procedure must stop before we delete all the vertices, thus leaving us with a graph with the required property.

Comment: Indeed, assume the contrary, let $n$ be the number of vertices of $G$, and let $k_1,...,k_s$ such that $k_1 + ... + k_s = n$ be the numbers of vertices deleted in each step (since $n$ is finite, $s$ is also finite). At a step $i$, a vertex $v$ is deleted if deg$(v) < \frac{d}{2}$. So by removing $v$, we remove less than $d$ degrees from the graph. And by removing $k_i$ such vertices, we remove less than $d \cdot k_i$ degrees from the graph. After the procedure ends, we have removed less than $d \cdot (k_1+...+k_s) = d \cdot n$ degree from the graph.

Comment: But this is a contradiction, since we assume we are removing every vertex and every degree, while $G$ has a total of $d \cdot n$ degrees.

Comment: Apologies for revisiting an old question, this appeared on my feed today. I wrote my answer before checking the dates or the comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oops, never mind, I figured it out! I'll post it as an answer tho:

So we need
$$
(n-1)\sum d_i<n(\sum d_i-2k),
$$
or in other words:
$$
n\sum d_i-\sum d_i<n\sum d_i-2kn\implies 2kn<\sum d_i,
$$
which is true, because $2k<\sum d_i/n=d$.

Comment: So the average degree increases, that is evident, but when a vertex of degree $<d/2$ is removed, degree of some other vertices might fall below $d/2$. What is the guarantee that we will be left with a subgraph where each vertex will have degree $\ge d/2$?

Comment: Okay I think I understand. You are trying to prove the problem via induction in the number of vertices.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, there is an algorithm that returns a subgraph $G'$ of $G$ where every vertex in $G'$ has degree *strictly larger than* $d/2$.

Let us assume that there is a vertex in $G$ of degree no larger than $d/2$ or we are done.  Let us see what happens to the average degree if we were to remove a vertex $v$ of degree $d/2$ or less from $G$. In fact, we claim that the average degree of $G' \doteq G \setminus \{v\}$ is at least $d$ if the average degree of $G$ is at least $d$. [Indeed let us write the number of vertices in $G$ as $n$. Then as $G$ has average degree at least $d$ it follows that $G$ has at least $nd/2$ edges. Then $G'$ has at least $nd/2 - d_G(v) \le$ $nd-d/2 = (n-1)d/2$ edges and $n-1$ vertices, so the average degree of $G'$ is at least $2 \times \frac{(n-1)d}{n-1} \ge d$ by the Handshaking Lemma.]

This gives an algorithm to find a subgraph $G'$ of $G$ with degree greater than $d/2$:

1. $G' \leftarrow G$.
2. WHILE there is a remove a vertex $v$ of degree $d/2$ or less in $G$:  $G' \leftarrow G' \setminus \{v\}$
3. RETURN $G'$.

As each time a vertex of degree $d/2$ or less is removed from $G'$ the number of vertices goes down by 1 but the average degree stays above $d$ it follows that this will conclude with a graph where every vertex has degree *strictly larger than* $d/2$.

Comment: Hi! I am little confused. Why do we care about the average degree of $G'$ (of the graph with deleted vertex)? Why is it so important that $d_{\text{ave}}(G')\geq d_{\text{ave}}(G)$?

Comment: For the induction to work, the average degree of the new smaller graph--the graph formed by removing a vertex from $G$--must be at least $d$ as well.